# How delete child after time 2 hours automatic ( firebase swift 4)?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift4

I have app game online by firebase swift 4
there is room for chatting 
I want delete messages oldest after 2 hours automatic
thank for all

Answer (score 0):

well if you wanna delete it in client side, you can use some `NSTimer` to fire a function where you would do whatever you want to. But I am not sure how reliable it is when you'll go into background etc.

I would deal with that kind of stuff on backend, where I would setup `cron` to do your job every 2hours.

Answer (score 0):

One good option to use could be to utilize a simple script running on a private server. The program (choose a language in which Google has a Firebase API) can just scan the Firebase database for messages older than 2 hours and delete those. Another option that doesn't require a dedicated server is Google Cloud Functions. Write a Google Cloud Function that, when triggered, deletes all a user's chat history older than 2 hours. This function could then be triggered for a particular user in response to this user logging in or a user logging in that has a chat history with this user.